# When appending tr to table thead using jquery each ,results blank rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to create `thead` with `tr` , from json object array. This is required as it's needed by jQuery datatable.

I have following script to do that , but creates tr with blank values.

```js
$(function() {

    var json = {
        "Number": "10031",
        "Description": "Solid Parts",
        "Factory": "Factory1",
        "LocationIn": "OutRack",
        "Quantity": 18
    }

    var parsed = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(json));
    console.log(parsed);

    var $thead = $('#tableId').find('thead');
    $.each(parsed, function(name, value) {

        $thead.append('<tr>' + name + '</tr>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableId" class="table table-condensed responsive">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need a table to be created with array name. Example:

```
<table id="tableId" class="table table-condensed responsive">
<thead>
<tr>Number</tr>
<tr>Description</tr>
<tr>Factory</tr>
<tr>LocationIn</tr>
<tr>Quantity</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Table is a combination of Row and Column, without column and row it is now a table, so first you need to add row and then append all the columns in that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly add value to TR tag,

you should add tr and then append the column value inside the TR,

Try something like below.

```js
$(function() {

    var json = {
        "Number": "10031",
        "Description": "Solid Parts",
        "Factory": "Factory1",
        "LocationIn": "OutRack",
        "Quantity": 18
    }

    var parsed =  $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(json));
    console.log(parsed);

    var $thead = $('#tableId').find('thead');
    var tr = $("<tr>");
    $thead.append(tr);
    $.each(parsed, function(name, value) {

        $(tr).append('<th>' + name + '</th>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableId" class="table table-condensed responsive" border="1">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are very close, just a few mistakes
https://jsfiddle.net/k7arxht2/11/

```
  var json = {
    "Number": "10031",
    "Description": "Solid Parts",
    "Factory": "Factory1",
    "LocationIn": "OutRack",
    "Quantity": 18
  }

  var parsed = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(json));

  var headers = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parsed).map(function(hdr) {
    return "<th>" + hdr + "</th>";
  });
  $('#tableId thead').append("<tr>" + headers + "</tr>");
```